# Da pra criar variavel no git?

Tags: git

queria saber se é possivel criar uma variavel no git para que salve os diretórios.

se eu digitar apenas uma palavra ou algo do tipo e ele ir automaticamente para o diretorio salvo e tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para salvar vc pode usar:

```
declare nomedavariavel=c/ocaminho...
```

e para usar a variavel use `$`+a variavel:

```
cd $nomedavariavel
```